# JSTL objects in the url, not in tag context

Tags: java, html, jsp, el

So I'm writing a Spring 3 webapp with JSP views and JSTL tags. They normally work great, but there's this one controller call that doesn't grab the tags properly.

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(
    new RedirectView(RequestUtil.getWebAppRoot(request) + clientShortName, false)
);
mav.addObject("status","Session for interface successfully removed");
return mav;
```

So when I go to reference it in my view, I'll have a line that looks like:

```
<p>status="${status}"</p>
```

Which just displays as:

```
status=""
```

Now I would normally just dismiss this as something causing my view to render improperly, but I actually found this sitting appended to my URL:

```
?status=Session+for+interface+zFXDEV3+successfully+removed
```

So this leaves me with two questions:

1. Why can't I reference the object from a JSTL tag?
2. If I can't get it as a part of the tag context, what is it doing in the URL?

and for anyone wondering, the class types are:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView.RedirectView
org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView.ModelAndView(View view)
```

Comment: This is not JSTL but [Expression Language](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) (commonly known as EL). The problem is that EL will look the variable in the request attributes, but when you redirect to your JSP you have `status` as request parameter.

Comment: Is this line `<p>status="${status}"</p>` in the view returned by the Controller handling the redirected url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not JSTL but [Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) (commonly known as EL). The problem is that EL `${status}` will look the variable in the request attributes, but when you redirect to your JSP you have status as request parameter but not as request attribute (note that this is normal behavior when you redirect to a page).

For a better example (taken from StackOverflow Expression Language code), this is what is executed:

```
<%
  String status = (String) pageContext.findAttribute("status");
  if (status != null) {
      out.print(status);
  }
%>
```

You have two possible options here:

1. As stated by @SotiriosDelimanolis, your `@Controller` class for this URL should take the request parameters and add them as request attributes. Lot of work if you could add more request parameters in the future.
2. Use the `${param}` object from EL that gives you access to the request parameters. Using this, you should change `${status}` to `${param.status}`. End of story.

Comment: Just put it into production with ${param.status} Accepting this as the most pain-free and extensible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a `RedirectView`. The javadoc says:

> By default all primitive model attributes (or collections thereof) are
>   exposed as HTTP query parameters (assuming they've not been used as
>   URI template variables), but this behavior can be changed by
>   overriding the isEligibleProperty(String, Object) method.

So your `String` objects are added as query parameters in the new, redirected, request. They are no longer available as model/request attributes to the new request.

The `@Controller` that handles the redirected URL should re-add the attribute to the model.

Comment: I only agree with the last line of your answer.

Comment: Ah ha that make s a lot of sense. I'm going to give it a try and I'll accept it if it's good.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, can you elaborate?

Comment: @darkpbj look at my comment on your question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I've never used `RedirectView`, but it seems to me that's why his model `String` is added to URL as a query parameter.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza got that part, and I think you're right--but how does that make the first half of Sotirios' answer wrong?

Comment: Please refer to the link provided in my comment on OP and check *Javabeans* section.

Comment: @darkpbj `RedirectView` will, uhm, I don't know, cause a redirect? When you redirect to a new page, your request doesn't have any attribute, only parameters (which you can access) and you should set these as attributes. When you forward to a page (which is the normal behavior when returning `ModelAndView` instance), you set attributes in the requests that will be available through EL.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Well yeah, if you redirect, you are no longer working on the same model.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Nice. That would have been fantastic as an answer. I didn't understand, so I outlined my question clearly and concisely in the OP. I had figured that some community member would professionally respond in kind, and maybe offer some help when I ask for clarification rather than sarcasm. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: @darkpbj I've posted it as answer and another solution for this problem.